# How to copy blockquote text easily in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, contextmenu, blockquote

When we long tap in mobile/tablet browser then we get content selection option like copy whole page, copy selected text, share button, and search button

[image]

*[Picture copied from this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237936/mobile-web-disable-long-touch-taphold-text-selection)*

So can I select full blockquote text(`<blockquote>This is sample text</blockquote>`) directly without going upper or below?

I know I can't add another [context menu(callout)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8569975/5624827) but I am looking some solution which copy full text of blockquote in first/default touch and not just single word.

Feel free to add another way to copy/share blockquote text easily, but I am looking for lightweight solution. I tried [whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796908/5624827) and [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14224381/5624827) solution, but it make my page lengthy, since I have multiple blockquote per page.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: @MorrisonChang I don't think it's related. My understanding of the question is that OP wants to long-press the text inside the `<blockquote>` tag and have the entire block of text selected, without any text outside of the blockquote being selected.

Comment: @jdgregson True it doesn't provide the exact solution the OP is looking for but may provide an acceptable solution. Given the lack of what has the OP has tried, I figure a link for the OP to review and if needed update the question appropriately.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yeah, if nothing else works OP should be able to set an event listener to copy the text to the clipboard on touch or on click or something like that. But it would have to be clearly communicated to the user as it would be a non-standard user experience.

Comment: If I go with manual solution then I need many buttons like copy button, and share button for fb, twitter, whatsapp, hike etc. Which will make my page very lengthy for multiple blockquote. While share button in context menu allowed to share any text in all app automatically. Hence I am looking for lightweight solution.